# Safari: How to switch between tabs using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, safari

How to switch between tabs using a keyboard shortcut? I would access a first, n - 1, n + 1 and the last one tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Window Menu -

Show Next Tab  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>  
Show Previous Tab  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

[image]

Additionally,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[number]</kbd>   will go directly to tabs 1 through 8, &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>9</kbd>  = 'right-most tab'